# How can I use v-for with computed variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want use v-for nav items via my authority and another things.
this is my code.

```
 <template v-for="(subItem, index2) in item.children">
     <v-list-item sub-group  link :to="subItem.link" exact v-if="item.auth === true"  :key="index + '_sub_' + index2">
         <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title" ></v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item>
</template>
```

i want disable click `v-if="item.auth === true`

here is my object

```
children: [
    {name:'menu1', title:'menu1', link:'/company/menu1', auth: () => {return this.currentNav===0 }}, // not work
    {name:'menu2', title:'menu2', link:'/company/menu2', auth: true}, // work
    {name:'menu3', title:'menu3', link:'/company/menu3', auth: this.MyInfo.Auth.menu3Auth === true }, // work, but not changed menu visible on this.MyInfo.Auth.menu3Auth value change.
    {name:'menu4', title:'menu4', link:'/company/menu4', auth: () => {return this.currentNav===4 || this.MyInfo.Auth.menu3Auth === true }}, 
    {name:'menu5', title:'menu5', link:'/company/menu5', auth: () => {return this.MyInfo.Auth.menu5Auth === false && this.MyInfo.Auth.menu3Auth === true  }
}
```

but it not work as I thought

how can i fix it?

Comment: why are you making it a function? If currentNav is a computed property then you can just do `auth: this.currentNav === 0`

Comment: It's not permitted to use v-if in v-for. Move 'items.children' and your v-if condition into a computed.

Comment: @Mr. That's not correct.  Using `v-if` in `v-for` is no issue, they just shouldn't be on the same element.

Comment: @Ayudh, In v-for, when you add condition you are going to re-render all the items. because it may add/remove a new item so Vue cannot optimize it. and :key loses its meaning

Answer (score 3):

To do conditions on a v-for, move them into a computed property:

```
computed: {
  authItems() {
    return this.items.children.filter((x) => {
      if (typeof x.auth === 'function') {
        return x.auth();
      }
      return x.auth === true;
    });
  },
},
```

then

```
 <template v-for="(subItem, index2) in authItems">
     <v-list-item sub-group  link :to="subItem.link" exact :key="index + '_sub_' + index2">
         <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title" ></v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item>
</template>
```

It is the way you can treat conditions. In another way, you can do something like it, but it's not so clear:

```
 <template v-for="(subItem, index2) in item.children.filter((x) => x.auth === true)">
     <v-list-item sub-group  link :to="subItem.link" exact :key="index + '_sub_' + index2">
         <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title" ></v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item>
</template>
```